# Prefix key pressed. SDK Manager(M)

Tags: intellij-idea

While I try to type **s**, Intellij Idea shows me a message **Prefix key pressed. SDK Manager(M)**
like the image below(the red box text field).[image]

What is the wrong and what should I do now?

Anybody help....

Answer (score 1):

You have the two-keystroke shortcut for the **SDK Manager** action [configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html) in the IDE. Remove or change the shortcut for this action in [Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-keymap.html) settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by removing the keyboard shortcut. 
To do so

1. GOTO **File>Settings**
2. Type **sdk**
3. Right click on the SDK Manager and select **Remove S,M**

Here is the image
[image]